# While running H2 database it is listening on 0.0.0.0:<port(s)> how can I stop this?

Tags: java, database, h2

When the application is running that contains my connection to the database I noticed that there are server ports that start listening on 0.0.0.0 and I need it not to listen this way, I only want connections to be allowed/listening on for the localhost.

Is there a way to stop the database from creating these connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set h2.bindAddress to something appropriate, maybe your interface's IP[4|6] address maybe localhost depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I was doing this but it wasn't working. Eventually I found that you had to set the system property before loading the JDMB drivers.